# Problem with nltk and tensorflow taking endless time to pretict

Tags: python, tensorflow, nltk

If I run in my Mac it takes 1 second in worst case to run the model.predict()

But I wanted to deploy the bot in a server, so I cloned the repository in an ubuntu server (with vultr.com) and installed the pip3 requirements.

Than running the python script will block the execution in model.predict() and so the bot does non work

the problem is there isn't errors in the script, but I think is a problem with the speed of the prediction. it takes infinite time

using tensorflow in ubuntu there is a problem with cuda and tensorflow compability and the model is predicted with the cpu instead of the gpu

but is a very small inputs size so idk why tensorflow predict takes infinite time

here there are my code

```
from json import loads
from pickle import load

from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model
from nltk import word_tokenize
from numpy import array

path = "/root/Jarvis_V3/process1_classification/my_nltk"

model = load_model(f'{path}/db/best_model.h5')
intents = loads(open(f'{path}/db/intents1.json').read())
words = load(open(f'{path}/db/words.pkl', 'rb'))
classes = load(open(f'{path}/db/classes.pkl', 'rb'))


class MyNltk:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()


    def clean_up_sentence(self, sentence):

        # preprocessamento input utente
        print("tokenize")
        sentence_words = word_tokenize(sentence)
        print("lemmatizer")
        sentence_words = [self.lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in sentence_words]
        print("end")
        return sentence_words

    def bow(self, sentence, words_, show_details=True):
        # creazione bag of words

        sentence_words = self.clean_up_sentence(sentence)
        print("bow")
        bag = [0] * len(words_)
        for s in sentence_words:
            for i, w in enumerate(words_):
                if w == s:
                    bag[i] = 1
                    if show_details:
                        print("found in bag: %s" % w)
        return array(bag)

    def calcola_pred(self, sentence, model_):

        p = self.bow(sentence, words, show_details=False)
        print("predction")
        **res = model_.predict(array([p]), verbose=1)[0]** # <-- HERE THE PROBLEM: INFINITE TIME EXECUTION
        print("end")
        ERROR_THRESHOLD = 0.25
        results = [[i, r] for i, r in enumerate(res) if r > ERROR_THRESHOLD]
        print("result")
        # sort by strength of probability
        results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        return_list = []
        print(return_list)
        for r in results:
            return_list.append({"intent": classes[r[0]], "probability": str(r[1])})
        return return_list


    def getRisposta(self, ints, intents_json):
        # getting the possible targets
        tag = ints[0]['intent']
        list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
        target = "none"
        for i in list_of_intents:
            if i['tag'] == tag:
                target = tag
                break
        return target

    def run(self, msg: str) -> str:
        print("nltk run")
        ints = self.calcola_pred(msg, model)
        target = self.getRisposta(ints, intents)
        return target
```

thanks

I tried to solve the problem installing cuda dependencies compatible with tensorflow

but I encounter a lot of problems such as

- unable to locate cuda
- cannot installing cuda 11 because the installation fails
- if cuda is installed, no way that tensorflow see the right version
- I tried to delete, update all the things associated with cuda in stackoverflow

such as

https://gist.github.com/ksopyla/bf74e8ce2683460d8de6e0dc389fc7f5
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere-Bitfusion/3.0/Example-Guide/GUID-ABB4A0B1-F26E-422E-85C5-BA9F2454363A.html
https://gist.github.com/ksopyla/bf74e8ce2683460d8de6e0dc389fc7f5
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.0-download-archive

Comment: Hi @Andrea, Please have a look at the this [TF install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements) official link to install tensorflow  with GPU support as per your system OS.  Please ensure to follow all the Hardware/Software requirements mentioned in the link and set the path of the installed software (Nvidia, CUDA, cuDNN) correctly to enable GPU support in your system. Let us know if the issue still persists.